# Haskell - Sort List of Tuples by the Last Tuple Element

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to find a way to sort a list [(a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h)] by the **d** element.

So far I have tried: **sortBy (compare `on` snd)** but I cant find a way to get the 4th element and **not the 2nd**.

My output has to be the same but ordered instead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fst` and `snd` are provided *specifically* for 2-tuples as convenience functions. However, you can very easily write a function that works for 4-tuples.

```
frth :: (a, b, c, d) -> d
frth (_, _, _, d) = d
```

Then

```
sortBy (compare `on` frth)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Or just `sortOn frth`.

Comment: ``sortBy (compare `on` f)`` = `sortBy (comparing f)` = `sortOn f`

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own projection

```
get4thOf4 :: (a,b,c,d) -> d
get4thOf4 (_,_,_,d) = d
```

after which you can use `sortBy (comparing get4thof4)`.

Alternatively, use a lambda: `sortBy (comparing (\(_,_,_,d) -> d))`

(`comparing ...` means the same thing as `` compare `on` ... ``)